# How to re-use the same code for clearing text boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have so many text boxes and about five buttons. I want to clear the text boxes and do some other things which are repeating in all five buttons. I want to create a new class and put all the code which is repeating so that I can re-use the code through a function or method. But, the problem is if I create a new class, the text boxes are recognized. For example, If I say `txtFirstName.Clear()` in a new class, it is not recognized as it is a new class. Is there any way around ?

Comment: Pass the form object as a parameter of a method into the new class and to access text boxes write get methods in your form.

Comment: @Ravindra Gullapalli Can you please post a example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Utility class with static methods for the code you need to re-use all the time. An example would be a method that you could pass a container reference to it and it would clear all the textboxes (Or Make them read only) inside that container or any child containers. See code below :

```
public class utility
{

public static void MyTextBoxes(Control container, string CommandName){

        foreach (Control c in container.Controls){
        MyTextBoxes(c, CommandName);        

        if(c is TextBox){ 
          switch (CommandName)
          {
            case "Clear":
                c.Text = "";   
                break;
            case "ReadOnly":
                ((TextBox)c).ReadOnly = true;
                break;
          }  

        }   
    }    
}
```

In your `Form` code, call the method like this :

```
utility.MyTextBoxes(this, "Clear");
utility.MyTextBoxes(this, "ReadOnly");
```

This way I used the same method to perform different commands by specifying the command as string. You could have different methods do different commands (for code readability) if you wish. I'm sure this has given you an idea on how to create utility methods.

Comment: They are inside a panel :(

Comment: But it's not about clearing text boxes I have some other code which I want to re-use and that's why I want to create a new class and add Form1 Reference to it, but how ?

Comment: @KiritiK I updated my answer, what other code you want to re-use?

Comment: Once I fire Gridview selection changed event, I want the text that is displayed in the text boxes to be read-only `(For Example, 'txtFirstName.ReadOnly = true;)` and I want this be in other class and it should recognize this code

Comment: Sure I did gave me an idea about utility methods and benefits of it. Thanks a lot AbZy. I really appreciate your help. This solves my problem too!

Comment: @KiritiK I'm glad it helped, thanks for accepting (and the UpVote if you already did)

Comment: Masked text boxes are not changing to Read only. How can I set the same on Masked Text box as well ?

Comment: @KiritiK change `if (c is TextBox)` to `if (c is TextBox || c is MaskedTextBox )`

Comment: It is now giving me Run time error. There was no compilation error, thought it will fine. The error is---Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.    I tried                         `case "ReadOnlyMask":
((MaskedTextBox)c).ReadOnly = true;`
                            break;

Comment: May be I have to use another foreach

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the textbox reference to a new method on your class.

```
public void ClearTextbox(Textbox textBoxToClear) { textBoxToClear.Clear; }
```

just pass your textbox to the new method.

or to clear a bunch of textboxes:

```
public void ClearTextBoxes(IEnumerable<Textbox> textBoxesToClear) { foreach(Textbox textbox in textBoxesToClear) {textbox.Clear();} }
```

Comment: That code doesn't have to be on the same class, but I guess that the code that calls it would have to be. I suggest you look at Jeffery Khan's answer if you want to access the textboxes by name from another class.

Comment: I want the code that is calling should be another class, but how is my question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by passing your current form in as a parameter to the constructor of the new class.

```
public class MyNewClass
{
    Form1 _form;

    public MyNewClass(Form1 form)
    {
        _form = form;
    }

    public void ClearTextBoxes()
    {
        _form.txtFirstName.Clear();
        //Clear the rest
    }
}
```

Comment: `class AddtionalMethods : Form1
    {
        Form1 _Form;

        public AddtionalMethods(Form1 Form)
        {
            _Form = Form;
        }

        public void ClearTextBox()
        {
            _Form.txtFirstName.Clear(); //error here
        }
    }`

Comment: It is still not working. I tried the way you said, but it is not recognizing the text box. I have pasted the code above. Please have a look

Comment: The error is "The Text Box is not accessible due to its protection level"  in other class

Comment: You can change the protection level on the controls - if you go to the designer there is a property which by default is private. You can change this to internal or public - whatever suits your needs. The property is called 'Modifiers'.